# I have a service that is published in Android. How to browser it in iOS?

Tags: android, ios, tcp, nsnetservice, nsnetservicebrowser

We are creating a multi-platform apps for both Android and iOS.
Currently, we have a services that is published in Android with these information 
Type:_http._tcp or _http._udp
Name: abcController
port

Now, I want to browse "abcController" services in iOS apps to get the list of host (ip) for connecting. 
I'm trying to do it with these code

```
 NSString* servicesOfType = @"abcController._http._tcp.";
NSString* domain  = @"";

domainBrowser = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc] init];
[domainBrowser setDelegate:self];
[domainBrowser searchForServicesOfType:servicesOfType inDomain:domain];
```

However, it only calls netServiceBrowserWillSearch and doesn't have any response.

Any helps is very appreciate !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my issue.
It turns out that my service is published in udp,
therefore. withthiscode.

```
- (void) initBrowsingServices
{
    NSString* servicesOfType = @"_http._udp.";
    NSString* domain  = @"local";


   domainBrowser = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc] init];
   [domainBrowser setDelegate:self];
   [domainBrowser searchForServicesOfType:servicesOfType inDomain:domain];

   domains = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   searching = NO;
}
```

I can receive my service now.

Answer (score 0):

Your service name needs to begin with '_' otherwise it will be confused as being a domain instead.